# Efficient way to find column indexes by name

Tags: r, apply

I have a vector of column names as follows:

```
colsToRemove <- c("CHF", "CAD", "Sex", "Admissions")
```

I also have a large data frame with over 700 columns. I want to remove the columns whose names appear in the column name vector above.

I have been using a simple loop. It has worked to an extent, but errors when there is no match. Occasionally this happens due to variables being transformed and renamed. I'm curious if there is a more efficient way to do this, perhaps using one of the apply functions? Is there a way to prevent it from stopping at the point a non-matching value is encountered?

Current solution:

```
col_ind <- vector()

for (i in 1:(length(colsToRemove)) {
     col_ind[i] <- grep(colsToRemove[i], colnames(myDF))
}

myDF <- myDF[,-colsToRemove]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myDF[, !colnames(myDF) %in% colsToRemove]
```

If you need to remove all columns that (regex-)match the contents of colsToRemove:

```
myDF[, rowSums(sapply(colsToRemove, grepl, x=colnames(myDF)) == 0]
```

Comment: OP is using `grep`, I guess because there could be columns with names such as `CHF_1` in which case `%in%` will not work

Comment: Good point, although OP mentioned that it's a vector of column names. I've added a version that does that.

Comment: Thanks to both. @Sotos makes a great point and I was not clear about this at all. There have been times when I had column name variations that needed to be dropped, but that isn't always the case and I appreciate both of these solutions.

Comment: Another way to do it would be `myDF[!grepl(paste(colsToRemove, collapse = '|'), names(myDF))]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `match()`

```
cols <- c("CHF", "CAD", "Sex", "Admissions")
df <- data.frame(CHF=1, CAD=2, Sex=3, X=5, Admissions=6)
#  CHF CAD Sex X Admissions
#1   1   2   3 5          6
df[,match(cols, names(df))] <- NULL
#  X
#1 5
```

Comment: Or simply `df[cols] <- NULL`

Comment: as simple as that :)